# How to map Iterator's output to placeholder in loss function in Tensorflow using Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

Below is the code from tensorflow website regarding using the dataset api for consuming data from tfrecords

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_example, next_label = iterator.get_next()

loss = model_function(next_example, next_label)
training_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(...).minimize(loss)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...) as sess:
  while not sess.should_stop
```

Normally I define my network as

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_SIZE], name='INPUT')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_SIZE], name='OUTPUT')

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([INPUT_SIZE, L1_SIZE], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[L1_SIZE]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([L1_SIZE, L2_SIZE], stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[L2_SIZE]))

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([L2_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE], stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[OUTPUT_SIZE]))

input_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)
hidden_layer1_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(input_layer, DROPOUT1)

hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1_dropout, w2) + b2)
hidden_layer2_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden_layer2, DROPOUT2)

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hidden_layer2_dropout, w3) + b3)
```

and my loss function as

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

But now looks like it is not necessary to use feed_dict any more, but I'm quite confused about how to define the loss function in this new way, the sample code only show a single line

```
loss = model_function(next_example, next_label)
```

Can anyone help to give a detail example how to define the loss function, how to map the features and label to the placeholders? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placeholder is not needed when using DataSet apis any more, for reading data already a part of `tf.Graph`.

We do not need to read file in python code, and feed them when training, but read data as a tensorflow op in the tf.Graph, it will be much more efficiency for tensorflow ops mainly run in cpp.

as in your case, this to lines:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_SIZE], name='INPUT')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_SIZE], name='OUTPUT')
```

change into:

```
x = next_example
y_ = next_label
```

And **remove** the `feed_dict` when calling `Session.run`

Comment: he also needs to remove the `feed_dict=..` part from his `sess.run()` call

Comment: Then how do you feed tensors  inference time? Let’s say I have a `x_test = [None, INPUT_SIZE]` in memory. How would I get predictions on it?